# Praming Puzles & Colf: Condense a String

Tags: code-golf, string

Having spend some time on this site I have come to enjoy things being as short as possible. That may be the reason why I'm recently kind of offended by strings containing the same characters more than once. Your job is to write a function or program which *condenses* a given string according to the following rules:

- Start with a *0-condensation*, that is look for the first (leftmost) pair of the same characters with 0 other characters between them. If such a pair is found, remove one of the two characters and restart the algorithm by performing another *0-condensation*. If no such pair is found, proceed with the next step. Examples:
    `programming` -C0-> `programing`
    `aabbcc` -C0-> `abbcc`
    `test` -C0-> `test`
- Then perform a *1-condensation*, that is look for the first pair of same characters with 1 other character between them. If such a pair is found remove one of them **and all characters between them** and restart with a *0-condensation*. If no such pair is found, proceed with the next step. Examples:
  `abacac` -C1-> `acac`
  `java` -C1-> `ja`
- Continue with a *2-condensation* and so on up to a *n-condensation* with *n* being the length of the original string, each time restarting after a condensation removed some letters. Examples:
  `programing` -C2-> `praming`
  `abcdafg` -C3-> `afg`

The resulting string is called *condensed* and contains each character at most once.

---

**Input:**

A lower case string of printable ascii-characters.

**Output:**

The *condensed* string according to the rules above.

**Examples:**

```
examples     -> es
programming  -> praming
puzzles      -> puzles
codegolf     -> colf
andromeda    -> a
abcbaccbabcb -> acb
if(x==1):x++ -> if(x+
fnabnfun     -> fun
abcdefae     -> abcde
```

Detailed examples to clarify how the algorithm works:

```
fnabnfun -C0-> fnabnfun -C1-> fnabnfun -C2-> fnfun -C0-> fnfun -C1-> fun -C0-> fun 
 -C1-> fun -C2-> ... -C8-> fun

abcbaccbabcb -C0-> abcbacbabcb -C0-> abcbacbabcb -C1-> abacbabcb -C0-> abacbabcb 
 -C1-> acbabcb -C0-> acbabcb -C1-> acbcb -C0-> acbcb -C1-> acb -C0-> acb 
 -C1-> ... -C12-> acb
```

Your approach doesn't have to implement the algorithm from above as long as your solution and the algorithm return the same output for all allowed inputs.
This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

---

Thanks to [@Linus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46756/linus) for helpful sandbox comments!

Comment: @MartinEnder Riley's test case is still necessary, because it's the only one my Retina solution doesn't work on.

Comment: @mbomb007 Ah, I see. Good point.

Comment: Will the input string ever contain non-printable characters like spaces?

Comment: @mbomb007 No, to assume printable ascii characters only is fine.

Comment: @mbomb007 However as far as I know, a space *is* considered a printable ascii character, e.g. [here](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/space-ascii-code-32.html).

Comment: [Related](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94534/progruzzle-colf) (because of their visual similarity).

Comment: Please specify "character": A) any character B) anything but whitespace C) a word character (letters and digits) D)???

Comment: The result for `programming puzzles & code golf` is A) `puzlf` B) and C) `praming puzles & code golf`; but never `praming puzles & colf` :/

Comment: @Titus Well ... yes. In order to get a fancy title I took the liberty to condense `programming`, `puzzles`, `&` and `code golf`. I'm sorry if this irregular choice of *condensation-chunks* disturbs you, and I apologize for it.

Comment: doesn´t disturb me, only my code :) artistic freedom is great.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

```js
f=
(s,n=0,m=s.match(`(.).{${n}}\\1`))=>s[n]?m?f(s.replace(...m)):f(s,n+1):s
;
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Comment: Very nice, shorter than what I would have thought of.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>38</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

This should should leave the non-golfing languages far behind...

-1 for `$-[0]` thanks to [Riley](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57100/riley)

-1 for `@{-}` thanks to [Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada)

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN

`condense.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/(.)\K.{@{-}}\1// while/./g
```

This 27 byte version should work but it doesn't because perl doesn't interpolate `@-` in a regex (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521060/why-are-etc-not-interpolated-in-strings)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/(.)\K.{@-}\1// while/./g
```

Comment: How does the `@{\@-}` part work? I thought `@-` held the indexes of each match, so how does it "count up" on every iteration. Also, if you print `@{\@-}` before and after each substitution it only ever prints 1 or 2.

Comment: @Riley The `/./g` progresses by 1 in the string each time, except when the string changes, then it's reset to 0. If you print `@-` after the `/./g` but before the `s///` you will see it going up (use a test where the remaining string is large enough)

Comment: Printing `$-[0]` gives the numbers I would expect. Does `@{\@-}` act like `$-[0]` because of the regex context but not when printing for some reason? `$-[0]` is a byte shorter than `@{\@-}` if they are the same.

Comment: `"@{\@-}"` is not the same as `@{\@-}` (without `"`).

Comment: @Riley No, but `"@{\@-}"` is the same as `"@-"`. And this should also be true for a regex substitution but it isn't. Simularly `$-[0]` should work but doesn't. PS: You probably somehow had scalar context applied to `@-` when you did your print, so you always got 1 or 2

Comment: Why doesn't `$-[0]` work? It gives the correct output for all of the test cases.

Comment: @Riley You're right. I mistook my test output. A workaround for this perl bug at the cost of 3 bytes should prove useful in many places

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 35 bytes

```
rL{_,{{(_@_@#I={I)>]sj}*}h]s}fI}j
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ckx7Xyx7eyhfQF9AI0k9e0kpPl1zan0qfWhdc31mSX1qCgo&input=Zm5hYm5mdW4)

---

```
rL{                            }j   | run recursion on input
   _,{                      }fI     | for I from 0 to length(input)
      {                 }h]s        | one pass & clean up
       (_@                          | slice and store leading element A
          _@#I={      }*            | if next A is I steps away
                I)>                 | slice off I+1 element
                   ]sj              | clean up & recursion
```

You can see the individual condensations by [inserting `ed`](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=ckx7ZWRfLHt7KF9AX0AjST17SSk-XXNqfSp9aF1zfWZJfWoKCg&input=Zm5hYm5mdW4)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>117</s> <s>104</s> 101 bytes

Recursively do the necessary replacements. I build the regex dynamically.

```python
import re
def f(s,i=0):t=re.sub(r"(.)%s\1"%("."*i),r"\1",s);e=s==t;return i>len(t)and t or f(t,i*e+e)
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/DiEM/2)

Comment: The two return lines can be condensed into `return i>len(t) and t or s!=t and f(t) or f(t,i+1)` for a net of -4 bytes

Comment: Another 2 bytes can be shaved off by changing that to `return t if i>len(t)else s!=t and f(t)or f(t,i+1))`

Comment: Even more by `e=s==t;return i>len(t)and t or f(t,i*e+e)` and then you can remove the `i=0` in the function definition, but you'll have to call with 0 start.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the four spaces are there not because you're using four spaces but because SE automatically expands them. If that's not the case, you can change all your spaces to either tabs or a single space for -9 bytes.

Comment: @Quelklef The meta forbids taking additional parameters.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes If you click "edit", you can see the actual code I pasted contains tabs.

Comment: You can put `f` all on one line and use semicolons to save two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl <strike>53</strike> 52

Includes +1 for -p

```
for($i=0;$i<length;){$i=(s/(.).{$i}\1/\1/)?0:$i+1;}
```

Try it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/WyyE3d).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 90 Bytes

```
for($s=$argv[$c=1];$s[$i=++$i*!$c];)$s=preg_replace("#(.).{{$i}}\\1#","$1",$s,1,$c);echo$s;
```

or 92 Bytes

```
for($s=$argv[1];$s[$i];$i=++$i*!$c)$s=preg_replace("#(.).{".+$i."}\\1#","$1",$s,1,$c);echo$s;
```

Comment: 1) first version: `+$i` instead of `$i+=0` (-2).
2) `for` loop instead of `while` can save two bytes and allow to remove curlys (-4).
3) `$i=++$i*!$c` instead of `$i=$c?0:$i+1` (-1).
4) `\\2` is not needed, remove parentheses (-2). 5) You can allow limit `9` instead of `1` for speed (+0)

Comment: @Titus very good ideas. I had't see this Thank You

Comment: Now that I think again ... `+$i` doesn´t work  in every case. Try `hammer`. PHP doesn´t complain about the empty braces in the regex; but it doesn´t match as wanted. By the way: I count 91, not 90. But try the new 1) `for($s=$argv[$c=1];$s[$i=++$i*!$c];)`

Comment: @Titus Yes indeed I go back to `$i+=0` and will try your proposal later. What do mean with hammer?

Comment: @Titus okay the same problem if `puzzle` or something else like `(.)//1` but it is okay with your proposal or the `$i´=0`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 101 bytes

```
NestWhile[i=0;StringReplace[#,a_~~_~RepeatedNull~i++~~a_:>a,1]&,#,SameQ,2,ByteCount@#]&~FixedPoint~#&
```

There should be a way to make this shorter...

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>97</s> 88 bytes

```hs
(0?)
(a:s)!(b:t)|a==b=a:t|1<3=a:s!t
s!_=s
m?s|length s<m=s|a<-s!drop m s=sum[m+1|a==s]?a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7NaoQwEADgc32KcelBEaHSmxh8gd56bEuZxMSV5g8ngiw@e23M3twewsxkvszkivQjtd4VsM@9eOnLrMCWyrzgbSg3ZIwzbMPWdK8xUh4yyr8ZZaanTUs7hitQZxht2NWUD7PzYIAYLebDVM3xnr563A1OFhgMLgO/hPcwv1l4BgUXuaLxWtLlqa5B0rntZzfOaMxkxyR8LGL@wJbbLQ1JZjnyMxFukKPTKo0RMTkDtPH3Rg6YBD60ueAo4onxLgQ/m0kVK2NN2a5VlcxxUZ2VssitWmwSMf6zaZAK5X3LUey/Qmkcaa@F938)

---

#### Old 97 byte bersion:

```haskell
(a:s)!(b:t)|a==b=a:t|1<3=a:s!t
s!_=s
m?s|length s==m=s|a<-s!drop m s=(last$0:[m+1|a==s])?a
c=(0?)
```

[Try it on ideone](https://ideone.com/NkXY2C).

**Explanation:**

```haskell
(a:s)!(b:t)|a==b = a:t         --perform condensation
           |1<3  = a:s!t       --recursively compare further
 s   ! _         = s           --no condensation performed
```

The `(!)` function performs one n-condensation when given a string once whole and once with the first n characters removed, e.g. `abcdbe` and `cdbe` for a 2-condensation, by recursively comparing the two leading characters.

```haskell
m?s|length s==m   = s         --stop before performing length-s-condensation
   |a <- s!drop m s           --a is the m-condensation of s
    = (last$0:[m+1|a==s])?a   --disguised conditional:
                              -- if a==s       if the m-condensation did not change s
                              -- then (m+1)?a  then perform m+1-condensation
                              -- else 0?a      else restart with a 0-condensation

c=(0?)                        -- main function, initialise m with 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>75</s> <s>64</s> 57 bytes

(56 bytes of code + `p` command line option.)

Using string interpolation inside a regex to control the length of the matches that are replaced.

```rb
i=0
~/(.).{#{i}}\1/?sub($&,$1)&&i=0: i+=1while i<$_.size
```

Test:

```
$ ruby -p condense.rb <<< fnabnfun
fun
```